# How to plot selected columns of a Pandas dataframe using Bokeh 2.4.3

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

**For future visitors: My original question was closed as a duplicate, but the old 'multiline' function in the linked answer is depreciated years ago.**

I would like to plot a selection of pandas columns using bokeh, i.e. multiple lines in one chart. Code showing one column/line works:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 5)), columns=list('ABCDF'))

sss = ColumnDataSource(df)
p = figure(height=300, width=300)
x = df.index
y = df[['B']]

p.line(x, y)
show(p)
```

Now, how do I plot columns A, C and F in the same line chart?

I tried this, but does not work:

```
x = df.index
y = df[['A', 'C', 'F']]
p.line(x, y)
show(p)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show multiple lines, you need to use the `p.line()` multiple times with different columns. Note that in the below updated code, I have used `color` as well to show multiple lines. Also, reduced the df rows to 10 so you can see the lines clearly. Hope this is what you are looking for...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 5)), columns=list('ABCDF'))

sss = ColumnDataSource(df)
p = figure(height=300, width=300)
p.line(x=df.index, y = df.A, color="blue")
p.line(x=df.index, y = df.B, color="red")
p.line(x=df.index, y = df.C, color="green")
p.line(x=df.index, y = df.F, color="black")
show(p)
```

**Output plot**

[image]